# How can use azure storage from Lucee

Tags: azure, coldfusion, azure-storage, cfml, lucee

I am developing an application using Lucee.
Currently I have some files stored on an Azure Storage Account 
and I need to be able to read and write to the Azure Storage account.
Is there any java api or Lucee Extension that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful for you? Let me know if you need any assistance./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked @Adam-Smith-msft answer but I ended up using the code from https://github.com/paulklinkenberg/lucee-azure-provider so i did not have to deal directly with the Java SDK

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed Azure Storage SDK for Java. The full documentation can be found [**here**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java)
It has support for blobs, Queues, Android and other libraries.